# HEX TO RAW function for DB2 on z/OS

Tags: sql, db2

I need to cast an INT value *as* HEX (not *to* hex).

For example, given the value 1234, I want to transform it to x'1234'.

My first inclination was to use the hex function, but that does not produce the desired results:

```
hex(1234) = x'04D2'
```

I need a function or algorithm such that

```
my_function(1234) = x'1234'
```

> EDIT: Thanks to Lennart's answer I learned that it would be the equivalent of HEXTORAW or
>   VARCHAR_BIT_FORMAT which exist on DB2 for LUW, but not for z/OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this transformation using the [EBCDIC_CHR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_ebcdicchr.dita?lang=en) function.   This solution assumes your system character encoding is EBCDIC.

See this thread for discussion, and UDF: http://www.idug.org/p/fo/st/thread=43924

This user defined function is from that thread.  It will receive a varchar input and for each pair of values convert them to raw using EBCDIC_CHR, concatenating it all together.

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDFUNC.HEX2RAW(INSTR VARCHAR(1024)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(2048) 
DETERMINISTIC 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
CONTAINS SQL 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE invalid_hexval CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22007';
  DECLARE VALIDSTR VARCHAR(1024) default '';
  DECLARE OUTSTR VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE HEXCHR CHAR(16) DEFAULT '0123456789ABCDEF'; 
  DECLARE MODVAL INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE LENSTR INT;
  DECLARE I INT DEFAULT 0; 
  DECLARE J INT DEFAULT 0; 

  IF INSTR IS NULL THEN 
     RETURN NULL; 
  END IF; 

  set VALIDSTR = TRANSLATE(INSTR,'',HEXCHR);

  IF (VALIDSTR <> '') THEN
     SIGNAL invalid_hexval SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not Hex: [' || CAST(INSTR AS VARCHAR(59))||']';
  END IF;

  SET MODVAL = MOD(LENGTH(INSTR),2);

  IF MODVAL <> 0 THEN 
     SET INSTR = CONCAT('0',INSTR);
  END IF;

  SET LENSTR = LENGTH(INSTR); 

  WHILE I < LENSTR DO 
     SET J = 16 * (POSSTR(HEXCHR,SUBSTR(INSTR,I+1,1))-1); 
     SET I = I + 1; 
     SET J = J + (POSSTR(HEXCHR,SUBSTR(INSTR,I+1,1))-1); 
     SET I = I + 1; 
     SET OUTSTR = CONCAT(OUTSTR,EBCDIC_CHR(J)); 
  END WHILE; 
  RETURN OUTSTR; 
END#
```

Function usage:

```
SELECT UDFUNC.HEX2RAW('1234')
     , HEX(UDFUNC.HEX2RAW('1234'))
     , UDFUNC.HEX2RAW('1234567')
     , HEX(UDFUNC.HEX2RAW('1234567'))
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

results in:

```
 1  2    3    4
 -- ---- ---- --------
    1234   áÅ 01234567
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question, is this in the ballpark?

```
 with t (s) as (values ('1234'),(x'F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0')) 
 select s
      , case when translate(s, '', '0123456789') = '' 
             then hextoraw(s) 
             else s 
        end
 from t;

 S             2                         
 ------------- --------------------------
 1234          x'1234'
 ððððððððððððð      ððððððððððððð
```

Comment: Not in the ballpark.  Sorry my question is not very clear!  What I want to end up with is actually x'1234' as a hex value.  But I have the char value '1234' as a starting point.  I think I added too much extra stuff in there.  I'm not sure how to cast the char '1234' as a hex value.  Is that a helpful clarification?

Comment: I don't have z so I have to guess a bit, `, case when translate(s, '', '0123456789') = '' 
             then hextoraw(s) 
             else s 
        end`

Comment: Thinking about this more, what I need is a function or algorithm such that my_function(1234) = x'1234'.

Comment: hextoraw(s) should do that, does that function exist in z?

Comment: It does not exist on Z! too bad.  That would have been easy!  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sqlfunctionsintro.dita?lang=en

Comment: It doesn't have VARCHAR_BIT_FORMAT either, which the hextoraw function is a shortcut for.  Also a bummer! http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0024845.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-9-4-1-187

Comment: Josh, would my_function(1234) = 4660 suffice?

Comment: I need it to end up as a hex value.  An actual raw datatype.  So 4660 would not suffice since it would be the decimal equivalent of the hex value of 1234.

Comment: Serge Rielau has a blog where the code for a number of conversion functions exists: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/bit_arithmetic19?lang=en . I haven’t looked that close, but perhaps there is something there that you can use.

Comment: That's an awesome article!  Thanks. Unfortunately, converting to the right numeric value doesn't end up with the raw format.  I need something to go directly to raw, just like the hextoraw function.  Nothing exists like that on Z currently.  It has to be done internally, and everything I've found on Z does character encoding translation before it gives you a hex value.